# How to bound $\|A^{1/2}(B^{-1}-A^{-1})A^{1/2})\|$ where $A$ and $B$ are positive definite matrices with $\|A-B\| < \epsilon d$

Tags: matrices, convex-optimization, positive-definite, hessian-matrix

I am working on a problem which requires me to bound $\|A^{1/2}(B^{-1}-A^{-1})A^{1/2}\|$ where $A$ and $B$ are $n \times n$ positive definite matrices with $\lambda_{max}(A) ,\lambda_{max}(B)  < c$ and $\lambda_{min}(A) , \lambda_{min}(B)> d$. Here $\|\|$ means operator norm.

I am able to prove that $\|A^{1/2}(B^{-1}-A^{-1})A^{1/2}\|$ < $\frac{c}{d} \epsilon$. But is there a way to avoid $\frac{c}{d}$ and show that $\|A^{1/2}(B^{-1}-A^{-1})A^{1/2}\| < \epsilon$? I am able to show this when the matrices inside the norm commute but how to prove in general?

Comment: How did you derive your bound?

Comment: Your claim that the inequality holds when $A$ and $B$ commute is false. Consider $A=(\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\epsilon^2)I$ and $B=\epsilon^2 I$ when $\epsilon\to0$.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. $(B^{-1}- A^{-1})$ can be written as $A^{-1}(A-B)B^{-1}$ and we can use that $d \leq \|A\| \leq c$ and $ \frac{1}{c} \leq \|A^{-1}\| \leq \frac{1}{d}$. I used the submultiplicativity property of the norm to  show to rest

Comment: @user1551. If $A^{1/2}$ commutes with $(B^{-1}-A^{-1})$ then we get $\|A (B^{-1}-A^{-1})\|$ which can be written as $\|(B-A)B^{-1}\|$. We can use the sub multiplicativity property of the norm to complete the argument, am I correct?

Comment: No, both of your assertions are wrong, unless $\lVert B \rVert^{-1} \leq 1$.

Comment: Regardless of whether $A$ and $B$ commute, you do have $$
\begin{aligned}
\|A^{1/2}(A^{-1}-B^{-1})A^{1/2}\|
&=\rho\left(A^{1/2}(A^{-1}-B^{-1})A^{1/2}\right)\\
&=\rho\left(A(A^{-1}-B^{-1})\right)\\
&=\rho(I-AB^{-1})\\
&\le\|I-AB^{-1}\|\\
&=\|(B-A)B^{-1}\|\\
&\le\|B-A\|\|B^{-1}\|\\
&<\epsilon\|B^{-1}\|,
\end{aligned}
$$
but the upper bound depends on $B$ rather than on $A$.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. I missed adding one condition on B. $\lambda_{max}(B) \leq c$ and $\lambda_{min}(B) > d$